# Server-Side Blazor on Azure and Google OAuth 2.0 not working

Tags: c#, google-oauth

I am trying to create a Blazor app that uses Googles API to connect to Google and retrieve information about their People API, but the problem happens for all the APIs.

I am using this code bellow when i run in local it works and i get a new browser tab with google request for permission that i can accept and it works.

But when I upload to azure it doesnt work and the applications hangs and i dont get the new google tab request for permissions, any idea what is wrong?

```
@using Google.Apis.People.v1;
@using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
@using System.Threading;
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>


<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@Connect">Connect</button>

@functions {

    void Connect()
    {
         ClientSecrets cs = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                ClientSecret = "xxxxx"
            };  
        var userCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(cs, new[] { PeopleService.Scope.ContactsReadonly, PeopleService.Scope.UserEmailsRead }, "TEST", CancellationToken.None).Result;
    }
}
```